# Make an online HTML editor

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-editor

Can I make an HTML editor from JavaScript and/or Ajax? I have completely searched Google for a tutorial. It would also help if somebody could point me to a site that would teach me.

Comment: Requests to recommend or find an external resource are off topic at Stack Overflow. See the [help] for more info on how to ask on topic questions.

Comment: In addition to being off topic, your question is far, far too broad. Ajax is a huge topic by itself. Rich text editing (such as in an editable div) is another, separate topic. Learn each separately. Don't try to approach both topics as if they're one.

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible to make an online HTML editor. You will probably want to make use of a text area and an iframe. A good solution will involve javascript and possibly PHP. Ajax can be used to keep communication open with the server. A good approach would be to add an onchange event to a text area, which, when triggered would send the input via ajax to a PHP script. The PHP outputs the html to a file that is displayed in the iframe. The iframe can be refreshed via javascript and it will always show the rendered HTML, as it is entered. There are many sites on the web that do this. You should inspect them for further direction.